# How to create multiple directories from a single full path in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have this path :

```
dir0\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\
```

Is it possible create a multiple directory?

In C# (not windows phone) I use
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\dir0\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\")

is it possible in windows phone?

Thank you

Comment: You think there's a C drive in your phone?  [You need to research how storage works on WP.](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/06/25/file-handling-with-windows-storage-apis.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I solved
this is a code

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {
      isoStore.createdirectory("dir0\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will Create this directory path as well as well as  check for same path.

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
  myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("dir0/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4");
  if (myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("dir0/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4"))
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Yes");
  }
```